# Xamarin SDK: Key Not Found Exception

Tags: ios

I'm trying to do a simple query from Salesforce after logging in.  I'm using the demo code snippet given on the Xamarin SDK page.  I'm buildling a Xamarin iOS project, if that helps.  Here's my code:

```
String query = "SELECT Name FROM ServiceContract";

try {
    IEnumerable<SObject> results = await Client.QueryAsync(query);
    var e = results.First();
    Data.Add(e);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    new UIAlertView("Exception", ex.ToString(), null, "OK", null).Show();
}
```

When I debug, I can see that the internal JSON is as I expect, but I can't get through to it.  Whenever I attempt to access the data, I get the following error:

at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Json.JsonValue].get_Item
(System.String key) [0x000a2] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:148 at System.Json.JsonObject.get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.193/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/JsonObject.cs:49 
at Salesforce.SObject..ctor (System.Json.JsonObject restObject) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Salesforce.SalesforceClientExtensions+<ReadAsync>c__async3.<>m__3D (System.Json.JsonObject j) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator10`2[System.Json.JsonObject,Salesforce.SObject].MoveNext () [0x00059] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.193/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2270

What I noticed is that the return JSON doesn't have a Key specified on the first element.  I pulled the following JSON in debug from "results -> Non-Public Members -> source".

```
{[{"attributes": {"type": "ServiceContract", "url": url1"}, "Name": "Name 1"}, {"attributes": {"type": "ServiceContract", "url": url2"}, "Name": "Name 2"}, {"attributes": {"type": "ServiceContract", "url": url3"}, "Name": "Name 3"}, {"attributes": {"type": "ServiceContract", "url": "url4"}, "Name": "Name 4"}, {"attributes": {"type": "ServiceContract", "url": "url5"}, "Name": "Name 5"}]}
```

Notice the array doesn't have a Key.  It's just there inside the first squiggle.

Any ideas?  I hope I don't have to implement everything using my own Restful services, but this is making it impossible to even get data.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Gregory, just out of curiosity are you able to try connecting to different version of the Salesforce API? The latest version is API 32.0, and I wonder whether you get the same problem when you connect to API 31.0, 30.0, 29.0 or 28.0.

Comment: There's no way to dictate the version of the API that the SDK uses.  If I was writing all of my own restful services, I could do whatever I wanted.  But the SDK doesn't have any flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying effortlessly and consulting a few other engineers who have attempted similar things, the answer is simple: **do not use the Xamarin Salesforce SDK**.  For reference, I mean this one: https://components.xamarin.com/view/salesforcesdk/

I believe the library has been abandoned in favor of Force.com libraries.  I sincerely hope it gets removed to save other people the hassle of seeing it on the Xamarin Components plugin and thinking it works.  Instead, with a bit of finessing (and maybe some wrapper-classes), you can use the .Net Salesforce Libraries available in NuGet.  With the following two libraries, you can achieve almost the same things as originally expected in the Xamarin SFDC SDK.

On NuGet.org (or through Xamarin Studio 5+, right click Add -> Add Package), get the DeveloperForce.Common and DeveloperForce.Force libraries.

Some demo code I put together to show how to login as well as query (since that's what the original SDK only offered in terms of documentation):

```
var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(clientId, 
    clientSecret, 
    email, 
    password + securityToken, // Security token discussed below
    "common-libraries-dotnet", // User Agent required by the service
    "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"); // Endpoint.  May need to change it based on environment.

ForceClient client = new ForceClient (auth.InstanceUrl, 
        auth.AccessToken, 
        auth.ApiVersion);
```

The tricky bit is the securityToken.  If your SFDC instance has restricted IP ranges for logins, you'll need this.  If not, just password will do.  A post about the IP restrictions is here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpzqAAA

Querying will return you the JSON object type from the Json.NET library (which is pre-packaged with the Force.com libraries).  This library make JSON a breeze. :)

```
List<Object> Data = new List<Object>();
String query = "SELECT Name FROM Account";
QueryResult<JContainer> accounts = await client.QueryAsync<JContainer> (query);
foreach (JContainer account in accounts.records) {
        // Do stuff with the JSON object or whatever. I'm just Stringing for demonstration.
        String value = account.ToString ();
        Data.Add (value);
    }
```

In short, don't use Xamarin SFDC SDK.  Use the Force.com SDK.

Comment: For clarification on the issues with the Xamarin SFDC SDK, it lacks a ton of features. 

 - You cannot specify an API to be hitting

 - You cannot make your own login screen.  It uses an embedded view (which also doesn't even fit on an iPhone 4S screen).

 - The JSON parsing is broken since SFDC may not give you a proper key-value pattern for results.  Because the return type of the services is hard-coded to IEnumerable<SObject>, any attempt to retrieve out of the IEnumerable wrapper using LINQ fails with a "Key Not Found Exception" due to being unable to iterate.